# HP Mini battery malfunctioning

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, hp-mini

I have an HP Mini 210-1170NR netbook, which has been working fine for the most part for about 2-3 years. today I returned to find it powered off instead of sleeping, and when turned on it says that the battery has a very low capacity. the unit declares either 3% or 0% battery available when it's on, but in either case the unit immediately powers off whenever the power cable is disconnected. this would be a disappointingly short batter life in such a new computer, so i figure I'd ask if there might be other problems with it. is there a way to improve it or do I have to spend a lot to buy a whole new battery?

Additional info:
the power LED is on, but is white; Windows 7 now reports the batter as "3%, not charging"

Comment: Actually 3 years is probably a decent life for a battery.  Most Li-Ion batteries have between 300 and 600 charge/discharge cycles, and loose 20% capacity PER YEAR regardless of use anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the battery is finished, and should be replaced.